# Count the cells that value in excel

Tags: excel

I want to get the count of cells in each row that has a value in it.

ross    dan     bernard 3
    mary            2
rose        johnny      2

I want a formula that gives counts the non blank values in each row and gives the value in column E (ie., 3,2,2)

Comment: I'm unclear on your goal. It appears to me the the value for the 2nd row should be 1, but perhaps I misunderstand you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CountA function:
`=COUNTA(A1:Z1)`